# Apt autoremove removes nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but i updated packages on my system and it was recommending me to do `sudo apt autoremove` (i probably would have done that either way myself) but when i executed the command it looked like it wanted to delete my NVIDIA drivers.
Here is the list of the packages it wanted to remove

```
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libdpkg-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libnvidia-cfg1-515
  libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386
  libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-encode-515:i386
  libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-gl-515
  libnvidia-gl-515:i386 libxnvctrl0 linux-headers-5.15.0-25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-25-generic linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-25-generic
  nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515 pkg-config
  screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
```

I'm careful with apt now because i don't wanna brick my system

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo apt-mark manual xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
```

etc. to exclude package from autoremove list. To undo use `apt-mark auto ...`

Answer (score -1):

autoremove is nothing to be afraid off, it will just remove packages that are no longer needed.

When it comes to nvidia drivers on ubuntu you can open "Software & Updates" and in Additional Drivers tab you'll be able to choose/see which driver you want to use with your card.

Comment: this is incorrect, autoremove can sometimes break your system. OP did exactly the right thing by checking what is going to be removed, and making sure its nothing important.